# css less unrecognized statement

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to add gradients through css.

I have this line for gradients in older versions of ie.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#e4da9d, endColorstr=#c1b676);
```

However the javascript interpreter for less css is giving me a syntax error for that line. Is there a way to skip that line from parsing and just output it the way it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#e4da9d, endColorstr=#c1b676)";
```

More about 'escaping' in LESS - [String Functions - CSS Escaping](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e)

Comment: So, the only difference is that you wrapped the filter string in quotes and prefixed it with a ~. Why does that fix the OP's code, explain please!

Comment: @markus It's just "escaping". If you want use not valid css syntax in less - use it. Read more about it - http://lesscss.org/#-escaping

Comment: I'm not asking because I need to know, I'm asking because you can make this a real answer by explaining the mechanism behind what you posted.